# HTML5 Storage Problem

Tags: javascript, html

I have a notes box that can be used to store notes, originally I was using cookies to store the entries, then I tried HTML5 Storage and I can't get it to work, here is the code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$('#savesNotes').click(function () {            
    localStorage.nltwonotes=document.forms[0].todo1.value;
}
});

document.forms[0].todo1.value=localStorage.nltwonotes;
});
```

Comment: Did you figure it out? If not i can throw up a simple demo for you...

Comment: I haven't figured it out yet...

Comment: I think you just have an extra `}`? If thats not it either ill code you something, but i think its that `}` on line 4 of your snippet above :)

Comment: Oops, the code I put up there I stripped down and I forgot to take it out, so that isn't a problem.

Comment: There you go, working sample. You might as well use jQuery's amazing Sizzle selector engine since you have it as used in my example :)

Answer (score 1):

Here is some working code:
Preview (type in, then view your localStorage in your console) :
http://jsbin.com/exote5/

Source:
http://jsbin.com/exote5/edit

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('#saveNotes').click(function () {
      localStorage.nltwonotes=$('#note').val();
  });
  if(localStorage.nltwonotes){
    $('#note').val(localStorage.nltwonotes);
  }
  else{
    //Not set yet
  }
});
```

**== NOTE ABOUT THE FILE:/// PROTOCOL ==**
*You must have localStorage on a server (http or https). Firefox will not let you use them locally. If you are using a Mac you can use [MAMP](http://www.mamp.info/en/index.html) or on Windows you can use [WAMP](http://www.wampserver.com/en/) If you're on Linux you probably already know how to setup a local hosting enviroment with apache which is usually provided...*

Comment: How do I view the localStorage? (I'm in Firefox)

Comment: Firefox's Firebug is different than Web Developer Console in webkit. WebKit has a nice page to view all of them. In Firebug you need to open it, type something in that box then press the save note button. THEN in firebug > console type in "localStorage" and press enter. Itll show all the data

Comment: Ok, I see it.  I don't see it for my page, hm, have to figure out what's wrong...

Comment: Yes I am. Is the jQuery Sizzle selector engine included in the main jQuery file? (I'm using version 1.6)

Comment: Eventually it will be `chrome://` because this is for a Firefox Addon

Comment: Yes, Sizzle is what the selector engine is called :) File wont work on Firefox. You need to throw it on a server. If youre on a Mac you can still do it locally by using MAMP, or if your on Windows, WAMP

Comment: Needs "http(s)" in the front or else it wont work. I don't know about `chrome://` but i assume chrome will work, just not file:\\\

Comment: Not sure, but i can almost guarantee it. Hard to search for it because of "chrome://" and, well, chrome ;) but im sure it;s ok. But if that was the issue you should upvote me and check me off so others, hopefully, can catch this problem faster :)

Comment: Ok, I haven't tested this with the `chrome://` url yet, so I don't know (I found that issue too with searching Google. I wish they wouldn't ignore the slashes). This wasn't the main issue, (`file://` was), so I'm not sure if `chrome://` works yet. I'll have to see if it does...

Comment: Not yet, I haven't finished building the Firefox addon yet, once I'm done I'll try it.

Comment: I've tried it and it works, with a 'hack' (sort of). Firefox doesn't allow any local files (including files in addons) to use HTML5 storage, but I found a website that tells how to set the source of the storage to anything imaginable: [http://farter.users.sourceforge.net/blog/2011/03/07/using-localstorage-in-firefox-extensions-for-persistent-data-storage/](http://farter.users.sourceforge.net/blog/2011/03/07/using-localstorage-in-firefox-extensions-for-persistent-data-storage/)

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend using the methods provided to access localStorage instead of how you're doing it:

```
localStorage.setItem("nltwonotes", document.forms[0].todo1.value);
```

Then to get a value:

```
document.forms[0].todo1.value = localStorage.getItem("nltwonotes");
```

Though, make sure you check to see if localStorage is even available:

```
function supports_html5_storage() {
  try {
    return 'localStorage' in window && window['localStorage'] !== null;
  } catch (e) {
    return false;
  }
}
```

Otherwise you'll want to fallback / tell the user to upgrade their browser to one that [supports local storage](http://diveintohtml5.info/storage.html).

Comment: I've got FF 4 in Ubuntu. It still doesn't work! It works if I do something like: `$('#savesNotes').click(function () {localStorage.nltwonotes=document.forms[0].todo1.value;document.write(localStorage.nltwonotes);
}`

Comment: But that is just for showing that there is something there. If I do it outside of `$('#savesNotes').click(function ()` then it just says `null`

Comment: @NL2 Make sure it's active. Do an `alert(typeof window['localStorage'])` and see what it returns. It might work for the anon function because it thinks localStorage is just a regular variable that you're setting a property to.

Comment: Sorry I put in the wrong code in my first comment I was using `localStorage.setItem("nltwonotes", document.forms[0].todo1.value);` I put the `alert(typeof window['localStorage'])` inside the `$('#savesNotes').click(function ()` and it popped up saying `object` and that was all